# How to change font family of incoming HTML email in Outlook 2007

Tags: windows-7, windows, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007

After our company switched to Microsoft Windows 7 and Microsoft Office 2007 I noticed that most incoming email is hard to read since the default Microsoft Office font was used when the message was composed and this font looks pretty fuzzy. I know how I could change the format of incoming email from HTML to plain text but I would loose all the formatting in this case.

So what I'm looking for is a way to define a font for incoming HTML email, e.g. Arial, so that only the font family is changed but everything else is untouched (bold, italic, colour etc). I looked through all options and searched the web for a solution but couldn't find anything yet.

Anybody knows a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See here  http://www.slipstick.com/outlook/email/to-change-the-font-on-incoming-messages

"... you cannot easily control the font used to read HTML messages, since most people who send HTML mail specify the font they want their messages to appear in. If you’re bothered by that, you can follow these steps to set a default font and make an HTML message use that font.

**To set the default HTML font:**

1. In Internet Explorer, choose Tools | Internet Options.
2. Click the Fonts button.
3. On the Web page font list, select the font you want to use as your default.
4. Click OK to return to Internet Explorer. Note that this change affects web pages, not just HTML mail messages.

**To make a message use your default HTML font:**

1. Choose Edit | Edit Message.
2. Choose Format | Plain Text, and respond Yes when you’re asked whether you really want to change the format.
3. Choose Edit | Edit Message.
4. Choose Format | HTML."

Answer (score 0):

If the received mail has the font hardcoded,  then I don´t think there´s alot you can do. You can try changing the default font in IE. Maybe you want to read [this](http://blogs.technet.com/b/kclemson/archive/2004/08/26/221211.aspx).